# What is the minimum System requirement to launch janusgraph

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra-2.0, janusgraph, gremlin-server

I just started JanusGraph and my total RAM usage is more than 5GB without firing any queries. I have the following dependent services running

1. JanusGraph
2. GremlinServer (via JanusGraph)
3. Cassandra (via JanusGraph)
4. Elasticsearch (via JanusGraph)

[image]

There are some java instances running 
[image]

I am trying to find out the minimum system requirements for janusgraph but I am unable to find it mentioned in its documentation. Anyone has a link for the same? or any idea how much is the minimum system requirements?

Also are there any configuration changes to make it consume less RAM?

Comment: Found any answer?

Comment: Looking around for info about hardware requirements for launching JanusGraph with Cassandra, GremlinServer And Apache Solr I arrived in this good question. Any findings @Akshay ?